# How Can I make the World background Material to be checker Texture?

Tags: texturing, materials

I am making a cube whose material is **reflective plastic** [With Principled Shader], And now I want the background to be checker Texture,So that the cube reflect the texture giving a cool sense, My problem is when I choose the checker texture As **a background** I didn't know the scale of it to be **small** ... I tried a very big value and i tried a very small value but the two didn't work,what is the value could i choose to make the background checker texture ? I am using cycles render,blender v2.79

### I want this to be my background ...

[image]

### This is my settings [What is missing ?]...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a *Checkered* texture connected to you world background shader, then just provide it with correct texture coordinates.

From a *Texture Coordinate* node use the *Window* coordinate output to get a flat 2D-like background.

Adjust the size with the *Checker* texture *Size* parameter, and the proportions with a *Mapping* node.

They should be relative to the Render Output image aspect ratio you have set in the *Render Properties* tab. For example if rendering at 1920x1080 you would get $1080/1920=0.5625$

[image]